# CenturyLink modem - bandwidth use

Tags: networking, router, bandwidth

My smart son is running all kinds of schemes on his PC all the time, but I run a business out of my home and I need the fast internet when I am working. I was able to find a 'LAN device log' on my router, but all it tells me is that he is transmitting something like 16,000 packets, to my 35,000 packets. No bandwidth info. I don't have the chops to replace the router firmware - any other ideas to figure out how much bandwidth he's using?

Comment: It sounds like you should purchase a router, with the type of firmware options that will make this easy to determine, the modem you have does not have these feature you require.

Comment: It really depends on what he is actually doing. Do a speed test when the network isn't being used. It should be at your plan limit or a little above depending on peak times etc. Now do the same test when you are experiencing a slow connection, write down the results and compare them. You would usually deploy a bandwidth guarantee using the qos rules in the router for your computers IP.

Comment: Don't you really want to ask how to limit his bandwidth use? Or do you only *theorize* he's using a lot of bandwidth and simply want to confirm that?